# Ruby on Rails gallery using paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I'm attempting to create a gallery in Ruby on Rails using paperclip to upload the images. I have the models set up, where Gallery can have many images and each image can belong to only one gallery.

How do I go about making the appropriate forms? Are the images a nested fields_for, and if so,  is it possible to add multiple file fields so that the user can upload multiple images to the gallery at one time?

I used [this](http://www.joesak.com/2009/09/18/online-photo-gallery-payment-order-fulfillment-ruby-on-rails-tutorial/) as a starting point, but it used a different method of uploading.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen this?  I think this answers your questions if you watch all the way through.

http://www.emersonlackey.com/article/rails-paperclip-multiple-file-uploads

Comment: I figured it out eventually with a somewhat hacky method -- however, this link is great so I'll mark it as the answer for future searchers. Thanks!